# Fallback from FontAwesome if font download blocked

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I'm developing a web page and found [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) as a pretty neat way to add nice icons to things, however by default font downloads are blocked by the [NoScript plugin](http://noscript.net/) for Firefox.

This would not be an issue for normal fonts, but FontAwesome uses unicode characters which are deliberately outside the usual printable range of most fonts, so adding a font stack to the CSS (EG: `font-family: FontAwesome, sans-serif;`) will not work as all the icons just render as hex-squares.

I realise I can tweak NoScript to allow font downloads, but that is not the ideal solution for all users - I would rather the page degrade gracefully.

Of course, it would be easy to do this with Javascript/jQuery, but of course if it's **NoScript** that's doing the blocking that's no help either, and it fails the test if the user doesn't have javascript enabled.

What would be ideal would be to have some CSS style/rule that acts as the fallback for any FontAwesome objects, replacing them with some basic character or even just not displaying anything.

For those unfamiliar with FontAwesome / TL;DR:

All FontAwesome icons have the CSS class "fa":

```
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

FontAwesome loads the custom font like this (I removed

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
}
```

And then a particular FontAwesome icon will have its own specific class that inserts the relevant unicode character, for example:

```
.fa-star:before {
    content: "";
}
```

The HTML for the icon will look like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
```

**So the problem here is:**
We need some way, preferably in CSS, to replace, remove, or hide the content of items with the CSS class "fa" if the typeface "FontAwesome" is NOT loaded.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in CSS

Comment: you can have default font-family: sans-serif, FontAwesome; when css load and by using JS you can convert it to font-family: FontAwesome, sans-serif; so if JS is blocked default font will work.

Comment: @Faraz how will the default `sans-serif` work? FontAwesome uses special unicode characters...

Comment: @BenM here is my solution http://jsfiddle.net/farazilu/BG5J7/

Comment: @Faraz You just get a square > http://jsfiddle.net/BG5J7/4/ if FontAwesome is not loaded (i.e. when the `<noscript>` tag is enabled).

Comment: NoScript is a "power user" add-on well known to cause page rendering problems. If your site works mostly right with NoScript in its default settings, you're well ahead of most.

Comment: That's one view, I reckon NoScript is a pretty powerful protector of my security & sanity online and any site that doesn't gracefully fall back and work OK without JS is badly designed. Sadly, that's about 90% of sites, and an amazing number render a totally blank page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I **think** I solved this thanks to you guys leading me in the right direction:

In the head, I put this:

```
<noscript>
    <style>
        [class*="fa-"]:before
        {
            content:"+";
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

This selects each fa-icon class item, which are all defined in the pattern:

```
.fa-heart:before {
  content: "\f004";
}
```

And replaces the content with a generic character, or indeed anything else we might care to insert (including nothing).

Does this seem reasonable or is there some terrible side-effect I've missed here?

I realise there is a remote possibility that someone has font-loading blocked but javascript enabled, but for now I'm happy to ignore that customer demographic ;)

**Edit to add:**

After all this time this answer is still getting votes (thanks!), clearly it's still an issue, so I thought I'd post this link about greatly improving (and trimming) FontAwesome in a variety of ways:
 [FontAwesome Fixed](https://pixelambacht.nl/2016/font-awesome-fixed/)

My favourite is actually embedding selected icons as inline Base64 coded SVG, either in the HTML or your CSS. This seems pretty elegant and efficient, especially if you only need a couple of icons out of the set. FA still feels like a fudge to me.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't really answer the question. Disabling JavaScript and disabling Web fonts are two completely different things. It's only the NoScript addon that does both. You can disable Web fonts in all major browsers (for various reasons such as security or accessibility) and still have JavaScript enabled. Applying <noscript> in this case is only a very limited workaround which doesn't touch the core of the problem.

Comment: It wasn't done on purpose :( I first read the question on my phone, downvoted, planned to reply later but then had no time to check it again. I'm sorry if you felt offended. I'm not a fan of icon fonts in general because they are a very gray area in terms of semantics and accessibility. Many websites rely on them way too much (ex. GitHub as of August 2014). With Web fonts disabled they display meaningless Unicode symbols with no text or any other fallback on what they are supposed to do. Check http://technotes.iangreenleaf.com/posts/font-awesome-not-awesome.html

Comment: I'm aware of the hackiness of FontAwesome et al, and that relying too much on _anything_ in web design is a bad idea (the fact that canvas fingerprinting is a thing tells you everything about the state of the web / browsers), but that wasn't the subject at hand. I accept that the criticism of FA is fair, and that the comment on my answer (to my own problem) is a valid point, although I'm going to chose to ignore it in the specific case of the thing I'm developing as it's not very relevant - and I doubt our customer is going to pay a graphic designer to build a set of SVG icons just for us.

Comment: I would actually be myself interested whether there exists any (non-JS?) solution for the issue at all. From my experience with Web fonts disabled it's either meaningless Unicode box next to the actual text (not that bad), gibberish next to the text (bad but still usable) or Unicode/gibberish with no text (the worst case).

Comment: I suppose the only guaranteed solution would be to programmatically _insert_ the icons with JS following a test to see if the font is loaded, so the page starts off with no icons or some fallback image/svg in the HTML/CSS.

Comment: In the meantime I found this: http://jasonsantamaria.com/articles/symbolset and I can confirm that it seems to work. On their homepage (https://symbolset.com) there's a cart icon in the navigation menu. The icon changes to a word "Cart" if Web fonts are disabled / overridden without displaying gibberish or funky Unicode numbers.

Comment: I agree that this answer does not answer the title question correctly. I will not downvote, as it is well written, and does clarify that it only deals with NoScript plugin issues. I would however wish that @BenM's answer would be the one marked as accepted, as it actually answers the title question.

Answer (score 8):

One way to work around this would be to pull in another CSS file for `<noscript>` users, and override the `.fa-*` classes for images or sprites.

For example:

```
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="safe-icons.css" />
</noscript>
```

Your `safe-icons.css` file might look something like this:

```
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: transparent;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.fa-star { background-image: url('star.png'); }
```

Of course, you'll have the issue of dealing with icons pulled in from FontAwesome that have different sizes, but this will certainly strike a balance, and render at least something to users with NoScript enabled.

Comment: Web fonts are getting problematic as a whole in certain setups now. Like Windows 10 with IE11 may block all web fonts. This answer, while being a lot of work, is probably the only thing that would work.

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into problems where JS is enabled, but users are on a secured network that blocks either all web fonts, or FA specifically.

To fix it, I used something similar [to this](https://gist.github.com/AllThingsSmitty/716e8b64f04fbf4d21c3c63e54d4a487):

```
function css(element, property) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(property);
}

window.onload = function () {
  var span = document.createElement('span');

  span.className = 'fa';
  span.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.insertBefore(span, document.body.firstChild);

  if ((css(span, 'font-family')) !== 'FontAwesome') {
    // add a local fallback
  }
  document.body.removeChild(span);
};
```

Basically, it's a bit of jQuery that creates a FA element on the page and checks to see if the font was loaded correctly. If not, you can implement a fallback. In my case, the fallback was to insert an `<img>` tag with a generic placeholder graphic.

It's not pure CSS, but it (1) allows for more powerful fallback measures, and (2) covers more scenarios than just `<noscript>`

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an ancient question but I recently landed here wondering something similar.
I managed to solve my issue by just [hosting](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself) the icons myself.

> Example of my own html after following the above hosting guide.

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/all.css">
 </head>

 <footer>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
 </footer>
```